# How to ship requirements.txt to users without development-packages such as PyLint etc.?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm new to python. I use Visual Studio Code.

My current understanding is as follows:

For each project, I create a virtual environment. Now if I want to have some linter while coding, I need to install it with "pip install pylint" for example.
IF I want to ship my code to users now then I should create a requirements.txt.
However, after installing pylint, it looks like this:

```
astroid==2.3.3
colorama==0.4.3
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==2.4.4
six==1.13.0
wrapt==1.11.2
```

All these packages are actually not necessary for my code, they all come from pylint.

- How can I automatically create a requirements.txt which only include the packages relevant for my code (without pylint stuff)? What is the best/usual practice in python?
- Or is this actually the "normal" way to include everything and I should not worry about it that much?

Comment: How are you "shipping" the code to users? Is your project designed to a package that the user installs or an application that the user runs?

Comment: "If I want to ship my code to users now then I should create a requirements.txt" is not a correct assumption in the first place.  The `requirements.txt` file is usually used for managing a deployment, it's sort of similar to what some other languages call a "lock file". For specifying your dependencies, you want a `setup.py` file or a `pyproject.toml` file.

Comment: @IainShelvington it is supposed to be an application that the user can run, like the user gets the script so he can run it on his system.

Comment: @wim As far as I have understood, if I write a script which requires package A to be installed, if I give this script to someone else and the person wants to run it, package A has to be installed first so the script can run properly. It seems I misunderstand something?

Comment: That is correct.  And the best/usual way to do that is by specifying your dependencies with package metadata.  Which is what `setup.py` (imperative) or `pyproject.toml` (declarative) does. Now when other user installs your code with pip, it will also collect and install the dependency A.

Comment: @wim "when other user installs your code with pip"...the user would not install but run it (single .py script). And to run it, should the user not install all packages with the requirements.txt? I am confused now, need to read more into what the difference between "requirements.txt" and setup.py is.

Comment: If you have non-stdlib dependencies at all, then you probably don't want to be distributing a standalone .py script (since a single .py file is unable to specify its dependencies).  You can distribute a [distribution](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-distribution-package), and specify the [scripts or console_scripts entry points](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-scripts-keyword-argument) for the distribution.

Comment: Notwithstanding all the above comments, you could maintain two requirements files: `requirements.txt` for packages that your application needs, and a `requirements-dev.txt` for development-related packages.

Comment: @snakecharmerb the question is how to automatically create the requirements.txt? Normally, I would do pip freeze > requirements.txt but that would result into the requirements-dev.txt. Manually removing certain packages from the list is too much work and not safe. My current apporach would be to install everything I need while coding, then after my code is finished, pip uninstall everything and install only those packages again for which I used an import in my code. After that, make the requirements.txt again.

Answer (score 4):

You should create a `requirements.txt` file that has exactly what you need to run the project and a `dev-requirements.txt` file that includes `requirements.txt` and your development dependencies. The easiest way I have found to manage this is to use a tool like [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) or poetry.

For the former, you would have a `requirements.in` which lists your execution dependencies unpinned. Then in your `dev-requirements.in` you would have:

```
-r requirements.txt
pylint
```

You can then use `pip-compile` to generate the `requirements.txt` file and the `dev-requirements.txt` files and `pip-sync` to make sure your packages installed in your environment matches what is specified in the requirements file.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning pip-tools! FYI, you may found `-c requirements.txt` more convenient. See https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#workflow-for-layered-requirements and discussion https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/398#issuecomment-517972391.

Comment: @AlbertTugushev what's the difference then between the constraints file and using requirements.txt? I thought constraints were to just make sure a specific version requirement were met but didn't guarantee that something would end up being installed?

Comment: This approach might be useful if you want to separate base and dev requirements. If you use `-r base-requirements.txt` you'll get in `dev-requirements.txt` all the pinned base and dev reqs. But if you use `-c base-requirements.txt` you'll get only dev reqs, and all dev sub-reqs which intersect with base reqs would respect pinned versions from `base-requirements.txt`. By this approach you should install reqs from both files for dev stage: `pip install -r base-requirements.txt -r dev-requirements.txt`. Works with pip-tools like a charm :)